# parsing nested JSON using python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have a scenario where I have below JSON data, which I want to parse and store the results in a dict under these conditions :

Condt --> Parse through json and find under `data` if `groupProperty` is equal to `Tests` then return that `groupValue` and `value` in a dict.

```
{
  "dateFrom": "2020-03-26 07:35:00",
  "dateTo": "2020-03-26 07:40:00",
  "groupLabels": [
    {
      "groupProperty": "Tests",
      "groupLabels": [
        {
          "groupId": "1053777",
          "groupLabel": "testappzxco"
        },
        {
          "groupId": "570009",
          "groupLabel": "testappzkbo"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "binSize": 300,
  "data": {
    "points": [
      {
        "timestamp": 1585208100,
        "numberOfDataPoints": 24,
        "value": 0,
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupProperty": "Tests",
            "groupValue": "1053777"
          },
          {
            "groupProperty": "Test Labels",
            "groupValue": "61776"
          }
        ]
      },
           {
        "timestamp": 1585208100,
        "numberOfDataPoints": 5,
        "value": 4.888970,
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupProperty": "Tests",
            "groupValue": "1241460"
          },
          {
            "groupProperty": "Test Labels",
            "groupValue": "61710"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1585208100,
        "numberOfDataPoints": 96,
        "value": 0,
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupProperty": "Test Labels",
            "groupValue": "61770"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1585208100,
        "numberOfDataPoints": 101,
        "value": 0.01980198019801982,
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupProperty": "Test Labels",
            "groupValue": "61773"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "timestamp": 1585208100,
        "numberOfDataPoints": 104,
        "value": 0,
        "groups": [
          {
            "groupProperty": "Test Labels",
            "groupValue": "61776"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What I have tried and it doesn't even get the right details :

```
dat = json.loads(original_data)
testl=[]
for key in dat:
    temp=key['data']['points']
    for key1 in temp:
        if key1['groups']['groupProperty'] == "Tests":
            testl.append({key1['groupValue'], key['value']
                    })
```

Since the json is very complex I am not sure how to get the desired output.

Below is the desired O/P :

```
[{"tname":1241460, "tvalue":4.888970},{"tname":1053777, "tvalue":0}]
```

Any help would be great !

Answer (score 0):

There is no special problem here: you just have to be very cautious in writing the comprehension:

```
[{"tname": g['groupValue'], 'tvalue': da['value']}
 for da in d['data']['points'] for g in da['groups'] if g['groupProperty'] == 'Tests']
```

with the provided sample, it gives as expected:

```
[{'tname': '1053777', 'tvalue': 0}, {'tname': '1241460', 'tvalue': 4.88897}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not noticed that groups is also an array, this way it should work:

```
points=dat['data']['points']
for key1 in points:
    groups = key1['groups']
    value = key1['value']
    for group in groups:
        if group['groupProperty'] =='Tests':
            testl.append({'tname':group['groupValue'], 'value':value})

print (testl)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recursive search making fewer assumptions on the structure of `dat`:

```
testl = []

def search(obj, seen_data, value):
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for x in obj:
            search(x, seen_data, value)
    elif isinstance(obj, dict):
        if not seen_data:
            if 'data' in obj:
                seen_data = True
        else:
            if value is not None:
                if 'groupProperty' in obj and obj['groupProperty'] == 'Tests':
                    if 'groupValue' in obj:
                        tests = obj['groupValue']
                        testl.append({'tname': tests, 'tvalue': value})
                        value = None
            elif 'value' in obj:
                value = obj['value']
        for x in obj.values():
            search(x, seen_data, value)

search(dat, False, None)
print(testl)
```

Prints:

```
[{'tname': '1053777', 'tvalue': 0}, {'tname': '1241460', 'tvalue': 4.88897}]
```

[See Python Demo](https://ideone.com/QKO5GD)

Comment: What is the advantage of your approach over - Marco's approach

Comment: My approach only assumes that keys `value`, `groupProperty` and and `groupValue` are in dictionaries somewhere in the structure of the value for key `data`, but they can be arbitrarily deep within that structure. If they are always to be found at, for example, `dat['data']['points'][0]['groups'][0]['groupsProperty']`, then you don't need that flexibility. I was just trying to demonstrate "the other way." In other words, I do not assume that the ancestor of the dictionary that has key `groupsProperty` is a list that is the value for key  `groups`.